# Retrieving n values from treemaps in java

Tags: java

I'm using treemaps in my java program. The output of the program is a sorted map as follows

```
[cat=1, dog=1, pin=3, ball=4, mice=4..... and so on]
```

I want to display only first 3 values of the map instead of displaying the whole map.
I want my output as follows

```
cat=1
dog=1
pin=3
```

How can i do this?

Comment: if it's sorted, how come ball comes after cat?

Answer (score 2):

Add a count variable, set it to zero, and break out of the loop when it reaches three:

```
int count = 0;
for (/* the loop that goes through all elements of the tree map...*/) {
    // Do your printing...
    count++;
    if (count == 3) break;
}
```

I am purposely posting only a skeletal solution, assuming that this is a homework.